# Wordpress comments.PHP shows cached version on incognito BUT new version for logged in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I've been bumping my head around this for quite a while now. I've added some code to the comments.php function which is loaded on some pages. That code, however, does not work on ALL pages in the incognito browser, but strangely enough, it works on some of them.

When I'm using admin users, it pretty much works on all of them.

What can the problem with this even be?? I've tried flushing cache, disabling it, nothing helps. I'm using Elementor as well if that helps.

If anyone has any idea, I would highly appreciate it, any help is welcome.

UPDATE:

Wordpress sorcery has no bounds. Okay, when I find that certain "post" where I want to see the changes and just click on "Update" button with NO REAL UPDATES DONE in that file, it works and shows up new code from comments.php. But come on, I have tons of those posts, do I really need to "Update" each of them? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: What code did you add? It's hard to debug this without knowing what you did, as the code could be dependent on many things (user authentication, cache plugin, etc.). Without the code it's hard to debug this.

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information. good luck :))